# PgfPlots duplicate x-axis labels

Tags: pgfplots

I have some repeated numbers on my X-Axis.
Here is my code-

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotstableread{Figures/measurements.dat}
    \datatable
    \begin{axis}[symbolic x coords={1.2.1.a,1.2.3.b,1.1.3.c,1.1.1.d,1.3.1.e,1.3.3.f,3.3.3.g,1.3.3.h,1.1.3.i,1.1.1.j,1.2.1.k,1.3.1.l},
    x tick label style={rotate=90,anchor=east},
    grid=major,
    xlabel=Processor Configuration,
    ylabel=Clock Cycles,
    legend pos=outer north east,
    legend columns=1,
    cycle list name=exotic,
    %xtick=data,
    xticklabels={1.2.1,1.2.3,1.1.3,1.1.1,1.3.1,1.3.3,3.3.3,1.3.3,1.1.3,1.1.1,1.2.1,1.3.1},
    x label style={at={(0.5,-0.1)}},
    ]   
    \addplot table[y=App_Stop] from \datatable ;
    \addlegendentry{App Stop};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And here is my data file -

```
Proc_config App_Stop
1.2.1.a     138 
1.2.3.b     923
1.1.3.c     1708
1.1.1.d     923
1.3.1.e     138
1.3.3.f     923
3.3.3.g     923
1.3.3.h     1427
1.1.3.i     923
1.1.1.j     923
1.2.1.k     138
1.3.1.l     923
```

Now you can see I have 2 entries for example for 1.2.1 renamed as 1.2.1.a and 1.2.1.k. So in order to avoid these a,b,c...,l in the x-axis tick labels I have 
added the command `xticklabels=` in the code. However, it does not display every label I have added. However, if I comment this line and uncomment the xtick=data line, I get the correct output, however it has all the
suffixes a,b,c...l for every entry. How can I overcome this situation?

Comment: Instead of setting the position for the x label manually, you can just use `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5.1}` (or newer, seeing that version 1.6 has just come out). That will set the label position to automatically take the length of the tick labels into account.,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This gives the desired output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotstableread{data.dat}
    \datatable
    \begin{axis}[symbolic x coords={1.2.1.a,1.2.3.b,1.1.3.c,1.1.1.d,1.3.1.e,1.3.3.f,3.3.3.g,1.3.3.h,1.1.3.i,1.1.1.j,1.2.1.k,1.3.1.l},
    x tick label style={rotate=90,anchor=east},
    grid=major,
    xlabel=Processor Configuration,
    ylabel=Clock Cycles,
    legend pos=outer north east,
    legend columns=1,
    cycle list name=exotic,
    xtick=data,
    xticklabels={1.2.1,1.2.3,1.1.3,1.1.1,1.3.1,1.3.3,3.3.3,1.3.3,1.1.3,1.1.1,1.2.1,1.3.1},
    x label style={at={(0.5,-0.1)}},
    ]   
    \addplot table[y=App_Stop] from \datatable ;
    \addlegendentry{App Stop};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You just uncommented `xtick=data`, right?

Comment: @Jake yes; that's all I did.