# Duplicate values when writing value near coordinate

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, metadata

I am using this code, taken from my question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239011/write-a-value-near-a-coordinate-in-a-plot). The problem arises when two `x` values have the same `y` value. Then the `label` I want to write near the coordinate overlaps with the other one. How can I resolve this issue, even specifically for this particular input?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mydata.dat}
  x_0 f(x) label
  %some comment
  0.5 0.24 0
  0.5 0.21 0.1
  0.5 0.18 0.5
  0.5 0.21 0.9
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title = My title,
        xlabel = {$x$},
        ylabel = {$y$},
        legend entries = {A},
        every node near coord/.append style={anchor=south west},
    ]
    \addplot [nodes near coords, mark = *, blue, point meta = explicit symbolic] %table {Measurements/A.dat};
    table[meta = label] {mydata.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Relevant question lies [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69000/pgfplots-duplicate-x-axis-labels), however, I would like the labels I write near the coordinates to be separated by a comma, leaving the rest of the plot untouched.

Comment: I don't see them overlap.

Comment: @HarishKumar my apologies, I had wrong data posted. Edited, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [this answer by percusse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/225687/11232) and adjust the anchors

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mydata.dat}
  x_0 f(x) label anchor
  %some comment
  0.5 0.24 0  east
  0.5 0.21 0.1 west
  0.5 0.18 0.5 east
  0.5 0.21 0.9 east
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title = My title,
        xlabel = {$x$},
        ylabel = {$y$},
        legend entries = {A},
        point meta=explicit symbolic,
    ]
    \addplot [nodes near coords, mark = *, blue, point meta = explicit symbolic,visualization depends on={value \thisrow{anchor}\as\myanchor},
       every node near coord/.append style={anchor=\myanchor}] %table {Measurements/A.dat};
    table[meta = label] {mydata.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You have to add an extra column `anchor` in your data with the anchor values though.

While using `north west` etc use an extra pair of braces like

```
\begin{filecontents*}{mydata.dat}
  x_0 f(x) label anchor
  %some comment
  0.5 0.24 0  west
  0.5 0.21 0.1 {north west}
  0.5 0.18 0.5 west
  0.5 0.21 0.9 {south west}
\end{filecontents*}
```